# Exponential function applied to independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, independence

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be independent random variables over a probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F}, \mathbb{P})$

Is it true that then $(e^{X_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are also independent random variables?

If yes, how would one conclude that

a) $(e^{X_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are mesurable and

b) $(e^{X_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are independent

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: you can get a conclusion just using the definition of independency of random variables

Comment: @Michh think both assertions are true. Intuitively they make sense. a) I know that the exponential function is Lebesgue measurable but I don't know how it would follow that $(e^{X_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is measurable.

Comment: For the measurability, recall that the composition of measurable functions is measurable. For the independence, just write down the definition and it should be straightforward. @Shriya